# How to do this problem of csv in python by code

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with open('2015 USA Weather Data FINAL.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

I have file csv of 2015 USA Weather Data that the data will show information like this it have about 800k row in the file so i know it have 52 state but i want to know how can i find total state,Top 10 cities that has the highest temperature descending order in Celsius and Top 10 cities that has the lowest temperature descending order in Celsius by code

This is example of row in csv file
[image]

Comment: Please consider creating an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
You might want to have a look at the pandas library.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give a sample of your CSV file in text format i.e. copy/paste some suitable lines from notepad. This avoids us having to manually type in your data to test it. Also show what your expected output should be for the data you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas library

```
pip install pandas
```

Then the code becomes

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('2015 USA Weather Data FINAL.csv')
print(a["State"].nunique())
```

The rest should not be a problem. As suggested in the comments please look up pandas.

Hope this helps!